# Unable to connect to containers of a swarm in docker-in-docker

Tags: docker, docker-compose, docker-swarm

I have been playing around with [docker-in-docker (dind)](https://hub.docker.com/_/docker/) setups and am running into a weird problem.

If I run a docker container separately inside dind and expose a port then I could connect to the port without any problems. For example, using the [docker swarm visualizer](https://github.com/dockersamples/docker-swarm-visualizer) inside dind:

```
/home/dockremap # docker run -d -p 8080:8080 dockersamples/visualizer:stable
/home/dockremap # wget localhost:8080
Connecting to localhost:8080 (127.0.0.1:8080)
index.html           100% |*********************** ....
```

However, if I run the same inside a swarm by deploying from a compose file it doesn't work.

Here is what my compose file looks like:

```
version: "3"

services:

    visualizer:
        image: dockersamples/visualizer:stable
        ports:
            - "8080:8080"
        volumes:
            - "/var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock"
        deploy:
            placement:
                constraints: [node.role == manager]
        networks:
            - webnet                    

networks:
    webnet:
```

and the commands I run:

```
/home/dockremap # docker swarm init 
/home/dockremap # docker stack deploy -c compose.yaml test
```

now when I do wget I get connection refused error:

```
/home/dockremap # wget localhost:8080
Connecting to localhost:8080 (127.0.0.1:8080)
wget: can't connect to remote host (127.0.0.1): Connection refused
```

Should doing this sort of thing in dind be able to work by default, or is there something I need to configure? I am using docker **17.03.1-ce** on Windows and here is what I get when I run **docker info** in dind:

```
Containers: 2
 Running: 1
 Paused: 0
 Stopped: 1
Images: 1
Server Version: 17.05.0-ce
Storage Driver: vfs
Logging Driver: json-file
Cgroup Driver: cgroupfs
Plugins:
 Volume: local
 Network: bridge host macvlan null overlay
Swarm: active
 NodeID: wz2r6iuyqztg3ivyk9fwsn976
 Is Manager: true
 ClusterID: mshadtrs0b1oayva2vrquf67d
 Managers: 1
 Nodes: 1
 Orchestration:
  Task History Retention Limit: 5
 Raft:
  Snapshot Interval: 10000
  Number of Old Snapshots to Retain: 0
  Heartbeat Tick: 1
  Election Tick: 3
 Dispatcher:
  Heartbeat Period: 5 seconds
 CA Configuration:
  Expiry Duration: 3 months
 Node Address: 172.17.0.2
 Manager Addresses:
  172.17.0.2:2377
Runtimes: runc
Default Runtime: runc
Init Binary: docker-init
containerd version: 9048e5e50717ea4497b757314bad98ea3763c145
runc version: 9c2d8d184e5da67c95d601382adf14862e4f2228
init version: 949e6fa
Security Options:
 seccomp
  Profile: default
Kernel Version: 4.4.59-boot2docker
Operating System: Alpine Linux v3.5 (containerized)
OSType: linux
Architecture: x86_64
CPUs: 1
Total Memory: 987.1MiB
Name: 7e480e7313ae
ID: EL7P:NI2I:TOR4:I7IW:DPAB:WKYU:6A6J:NCC7:3K3E:6YVH:PYVB:2L2W
Docker Root Dir: /var/lib/docker
Debug Mode (client): false
Debug Mode (server): false
Registry: https://index.docker.io/v1/
Experimental: false
Insecure Registries:
 127.0.0.0/8
Live Restore Enabled: false

WARNING: bridge-nf-call-iptables is disabled
WARNING: bridge-nf-call-ip6tables is disabled
```

Comment: It looks like the last line of your docker-stack.yml file is missing. What other config do you have under the webnet network?

Comment: There is nothing under the webnet network. I followed the format in this tutorial - https://docs.docker.com/get-started/part3/#your-first-docker-composeyml-file

Comment: What happens when you remove the networks part for your visualizer service?

Comment: When I remove the network part of the visualizer service it works! Do you know why?

Comment: Hmm, actually now it works even with the original settings! I guess there was a problem with my docker machine a few days ago.